# Ansible converts int to float

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have below ansible playbook. I required output without decimals.

```
num: 100
var1: "{{ num / 10 |int }}"
```

Actual Output:

```
 10.0
```

Expected Output:

```
10
```

Ansible Version 2.7

Comment: try `"{{ num // 10 |int }}"` to get (floored) integer division

Answer (score 3):

The `|` operator in Jinja binds very tightly. In this case, you are actually performing the operation:

```
100 / (10|int)
```

When what you actually want is:

```
(100/10)|int
```

You can use parentheses to group your terms appropriately.  The following playbook demonstrates this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    num: 100
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ num/10|int }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (num/10)|int }}"
```

Running that produces the following output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10.0"
}

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "10"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```